# Articles in the "and" structure

Tags: articles, parallelism

In terms of motorcycle, the forecast sales is expected to experience an ascending trend from 2006 to 2017, with a significant surge of approximately 75k in the fist two years and ______ continuous rise to $400k in the next 9 years.

Question: Is "a" needed here? Can it be omitted here considered that we used "a" in "a significant surge" before the "and" already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "a" again. It's a tiny word and not immediately obvious that you are omitting it because of basic repetition.

---

However, some other things:

> In terms of motorcycle**s**

You're selling more than one, I assume.

> the forecast sale is expected
>    the forecast sales are expected

Your verb and subject need to both be plural or singular.

Also, although I'm not sure, aren't you talking about a "sales forecast", rather than "forecast sales"?

> to experience an ascending trend

I would say "to trend upwards". The original phrasing feels a bit clumsy.

> 75k  => $75k
>   $400k

I'm not so sure on the "k". I'm not saying it's incorrect; but I would only use this when speaking, not when writing. However, this can be accepted by whoever reads this report.

> in the fi**r**st *two* years
>   in the next *9* years

I would try to be consistent in whether you're using numbers or words ("two" versus "9"). The financial data can of course be expressed in numbers, but at least try to maintain consistency for smaller numbers that have no financial value attached.

Comment: typed in a rush, and obviously you spotted them all :)